# iTunes 12.4.1 cannot sync music to my iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, itunes-store

I have tried syncing mp3 files I downloaded from a youtube converter (youtube-mp3.org), imported them to iTunes and then tried unsucessfully to sync them. My school has requested that I download a certain list of apps to use at school, i don't have an Apple ID so my dad synced the apps using his computer. Problem is that my iPad only syncs to his computer ever since he synced the apps. Are there any FREE solutions to fix this?

Comment: The school instructions to download apps should have the steps they want. Without sharing those details, we can't begin to know your available options other than erase the device and ask the school to set up your Apple ID.

Comment: It was a list of apps, no instructions how to download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply enabled "Manually manage Music and Videos" in iTunes and then dragged the music to my iPad via "On my Device" in iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you had better [create a free Apple ID.](https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create)

I think [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) is what you need. A tool for iOS management from Mac/PC(without syncing iTunes and using an Apple ID). [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) is another app that is a little bit easier to use.

Comment: I don't want a Apple ID, you cannot delete your information from Apple.